# About time presentation. The latest News should be restricted before 24 hours ago from current time?

Tags: time

I have a web service to provide News.
But by the contract, I can only show the latest News before 24 hours ago.

That is, if today is 2015-11-24, the news I provided should be before 2015-11-23

Can I say that in this way.

`The latest News we published should be restricted before 24 hours ago from current time?`

it just sounds strange and ambiguous, how could I change the above sentence, thanks

Comment: Do you mean you can only report on things that happened in the last 24 hours, or before those 24 hours?

Comment: Before those 24 hours, if today is 2015-11-24 , I can only output the news between long long ago to 2015-11-23

Comment: Do you want to start with  "I" to make it personal, or "We" to sound like a company?

Comment: @RileyFrancisco id like to use we to sound like a company

Answer (score 1):

Try this: "News from the last 24 hours may not be posted."

Or in a positive manner: "News posted to this site must be at least 24 hours old."

Comment: Disregarding the *old news* oxymoron, of course :) .

Answer (score 0):

The Story you report needs to be submitted  2 days after it happens.

Is that what you're trying to say?
Replace 2 days with another number, if that is what you are trying to say.

Comment: Seems not what I need I changed my sentence on the orig post to make it more clear

Comment: So you solved it